# Change HTML+Unicode to string in swift

Tags: html, ios, swift, unicode, uitextview

I want to change the api return html+unicode to string in TextView. But i notice there's weird symbol. And i dont know how can i change that to appropriate symbol. Right now im using this extension :

```
extension String {
    var html2String:NSAttributedString {
        return try! NSAttributedString(data:data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: true)!, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType], documentAttributes: nil)
    }
    var localized: String {
        return NSLocalizedString(self, tableName: nil, bundle: Bundle.main, value: "", comment: "")
    }
}
```

and my current Code is :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupWhiteLeftButton()
        //self.navigationItem.title = "About".capitalized
        let htmlString = str.html2String
        txtView.attributedText = htmlString

        txtView.font = UIFont(name: "Play", size: 14.0)
        txtView.tintColor = UIColor(red: 228/255, green: 49/255, blue: 23/255, alpha: 1.0)
        txtView.isEditable = false;

        txtView.scrollsToTop = true
        let contentHeight = txtView.contentSize.height
        let offSet = txtView.contentOffset.x
        let contentOffset = contentHeight - offSet
        txtView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -contentOffset)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
  }
```

and the result is [image]

if u can see there's weird symbol around the text. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Use [SwiftSoup](https://github.com/scinfu/SwiftSoup)

### Exemple

To parse a HTML document:

```
let html = "<html><head><title>First parse</title></head><body><p>Parsed HTML into a doc.</p></body></html>"
let doc: Document = try SwiftSoup.parse(html)
let myText = try doc.text()
```

- unclosed tags (e.g. `<p>Lorem <p>Ipsum` parses to `<p>Lorem</p> <p>Ipsum</p>`)
- implicit tags (e.g. a naked `<td>Table data</td>` is wrapped into a `<table><tr><td>...`)
- reliably creating the document structure (`html` containing a `head` and `body`, and only appropriate elements within the head)

#### The object model of a document

- Documents consist of Elements and TextNodes
- The inheritance chain is: `Document` extends `Element` extends `Node.TextNode` extends `Node`.
- An Element contains a list of children Nodes, and has one parent Element. They also have provide a filtered list of child Elements only.